# HTML input type number seems to be allowing a letter after a number

Tags: html, input, types, numbers, html-helper

I'm using standard HTML TextBoxFor helpers in an MVC5 project and wanted to set a textbox to accept numeric values only.
So I've set the type to be number.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PP_IMP_M1, "{0:0}", new { @type ="number"})
```

I'm not sure what the functionality of the HTML input type=number is supposed to be but when I type only letters in the textbox and tab out, the textbox clears itself as the value was not numeric. This is expected and correct.
However, if I type the first character as a number and follow this with random letters then the mixed text value remains in the textbox. I know the character 'e' may have been acceptable but I'm entering things like '12hgf' & '45dddd' and the textbox accepts the value after I tab out.

Is this the expected behaviour for an input with type set as number?
I was hoping the type=number would only accept numeric values without me having to use javascript or jquery.

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Shuja

Comment: Which browser are you using? Chrome (my version is 49.0) won't even allow you to enter other than 1-9 and 'e' and '-' (minus sign) and '.' (decimal separator)

Comment: The browser I'm using is IE 11